# Communication with NAVision with SOAP API from SQL

Tags: sql-server, api, soap, navision

I have a problem with GET method from API. So, I had some code for body for GET method, and when I copy this code to postman works fine.

```
    set @requestBody = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <s:Body>
                        <ReadMultiple xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/rfidtransferlines">
                                <filter>
                                    <Field>Document_No</Field>
                                    <Criteria>PN21-001126</Criteria>
                                </filter>   
                        </ReadMultiple>
                        </s:Body>
                        </s:Envelope>'

    print @requestBody
```

Now, I want to get data from API, and I have code for GET method:

```
-- Open the connection.
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;    --MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false',@username,@password;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Connection', 'keep-alive'; 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'SOAPAction', 'ReadMultiple'; 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'send',NULL,@requestBody;

-- Handle the response.
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @statusCode OUT;
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @statusCode + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;
```

I think that problem is here :

```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'send',NULL,@requestBody;
```

or maybe my variable:

```
 DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(4000);
```

is set to 4000 characters, because is max for SQL Server.

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Seriously, SQL Server is the last place you should be doing that sort of thing. Write a service to do it.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I use urgent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: For the love of FSM, please don't use OLE Automation methods any more (sp_OA*). There are reasons they're disabled by default. They're not usable outside of Windows-hosted SQL Server. They're not thread safe. They're inefficient. Correctly handling error results and object disposal is beyond most people's capabilities. Perform web service interactions in processes external to SQL Server.